# Update query not working in table adapter

Tags: c#, ms-access, dataset, tableadapter

I have a table adapter on which I want to query an update to my database.

```
UPDATE Polls
SET DateRequest = ?
WHERE (Id = ?)
```

But it's not working when I try to execute it

```
_pollsAdapter.UpdatePollById(id, DateTime.Parse(RequestedDateBox.Text).ToOADate());
```

The adapter also has some other queries for selecting or inserting and they all work perfectly fine.

I checked if the `id` is correct or if any other error in the statement could cause it to not work, but then I would get an exception, wouldn't I?

Also, if I check for the return value, I get `0` - so the query actually edited no rows, but I can't see any reason why. The `id` is correct, the statement is correctly created within the table adapter, it throws no syntax or whatsoever-errors...

How could I debug this matter more?

Comment: What DB are you using? Oracle or SQL Server?

Comment: An Access Database that is operated via `OleDB` for C#

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query shows DateRequest and the ID, so you need to pass the parameters in the same order. You are passing ID first.

-- http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vbgeneral/thread/8f09bdd7-ba53-4f0c-95c4-cdcb35dea4f2

Comment: But why can I alter the order of parameters in the Designer then?

Comment: Well, still your note was correct and it solved the problem. Thanks =)